# How to implement form validation in ember-cli app?

Tags: forms, validation, ember.js, ember-cli

I am developing a Ember-CLI app. I have installed

- ember-forms via bower
- ember-validations via npm

The form is generated properly. But the validations are not triggered.

```
{{#em-form model=controller class="col-md-5"}}
  {{em-input property="title" label="Title" placeholder="Title"}}
  {{em-text property="description" label="Description" placeholder="Description"}}
{{/em-form}}
```

The controller code with validations is

```
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    submit: function() {
    }
  },
  validations: {
    title: {
      presence: true,
      length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 10 }
    }
  }
});
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs "You need to mixin EmberValidations.Mixin into any Ember.Object you want to add validations to". It seems something like this would work:

```
import Ember from "ember";
import EmberValidations from 'ember-validations';

export default Ember.Controller.extend(EmberValidations.Mixin, {
  actions: {
    submit: function() {
    }
  },
  validations: {
    title: {
      presence: true,
      length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 10 }
    }
  }
});
```